# Cannot infer appropriate lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am still having problems with lifetimes in Rust. I want to use a closure that implements a trait that returns a reference, but I can't figure out how to make the compiler happy.

This is kind of an extension of [this question I asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194367/expected-bound-lifetime-parameter-found-concrete-lifetime)
which I got working, but now when I add a closure to the program it won't compile.

I think part of my problem is I don't really understand the difference between declaring a lifetime in an `impl` block, and using `for` in a `where` clause.

If I can get it to work using [lifetimes in an impl block](http://is.gd/GFE1Mv) or [lifetimes in a `for` block](http://is.gd/cy3PX9), I would be happy, but I would also like to know the difference between them.

Edit: The last 2 links are links to a Rust playground with code I can't get to compile. The first link is also shown below:

```
pub struct Response<'a>{
    data: &'a str
}

pub enum Action<'a>{
    Next(Response<'a>),
    Done
}

pub trait Handler<'a>: Send + Sync{
    fn handle(&self, res: Response<'a>) -> Action<'a>;
}

impl<'a, T> Handler<'a> for T
where T: Send + Sync + Fn(Response<'a>) -> Action<'a> {
    fn handle(&self, res: Response<'a>) -> Action<'a>{
        (*self)(res)
    }
}

fn main(){
    println!("running");
    do_something_with_handler(|res: Response| -> Action{
        //this closure should implement Handler

        //Action::Done //This compiles if Done is returned instead of Next
        Action::Next(res)
    });
}

pub fn do_something_with_handler<'a, T>(handler: T) where T: Handler<'a> + 'static{
    //do something here
}

// This isn't used in this example, but I want to make sure the trait
// can still be implemented for arbitrary types
struct SomethingElse;

impl<'a> Handler<'a> for SomethingElse{
    fn handle(&self, res: Response<'a>) -> Action<'a>{
        Action::Next(res)
    }
}
```

Comment: A reduction of the problem to its essence: [something with `let f = |s| s; h(f);` does not work](http://is.gd/RIrNxZ), [*but something with `h(|s| s);` does*](http://is.gd/GJHrXc).

Comment: This is a bit vague, could you post the not working code?

Comment: @MatthieuM. The not working code was in a link to a Rust Playground, but I edited the question to make this more obvious

Comment: @NathanFuchs: Thanks, in general SO favors content to be *on SO*, because links go stale (especially minified URLs, they have a short expiry date).

Comment: Amusingly, removing some type annotations from your second example gets it working: http://is.gd/jswjjB

Comment: @ChrisMorgan your simplified example seems like a compiler bug. Is there a tracking issue for this in Github?

Comment: @Rym Your code doesn't compile anymore.

Comment: My guess is it's related to this change: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1214